# jquery: read div id and remove appropriate div?

Tags: jquery

hey, 
had no idea what title this post should have, hard to describe :)

i have a dynamic id's with a number

```
<div id="post-full-116">Content</div>

<div id="post-116">Content</div>
```

i want to query the dynamic number (in this case 116) of id="post-full-116" and if another div on the page with id="post-116" exists i want to remove that.

sounds weird i know. so you get the idea behind it, the div with id="post-number" holds a preview of a post and the the div with id="post-full-number" holds the full content of a post.

i don't want to show the preview of a post if the full post is already shown - so i simply want to hide it with jquery. i know i should do that on the serverside before, however in this case jquery would be perfect.

any idea how i can query the number of the dynamic id and the remove the appropriate div with the same number?

thank you

Comment: these divs wouldn't happen to have classes of any sort would they? `class="post"` would help a lot to make the selection easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you would do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^=post-full]').each(function() {
         var num = $(this).attr('id').replace(/post\-full\-/,'');
         $('#post-' + num).hide();
    });
});
```

That should grab any "full" posts, find the number of the post, and hide the "preview" version of it.

UPDATE:

Here's a live demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/saUQf/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div[id^="post-full"]').each(function(){
    $('#post-' + this.id.split('-')[2]).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.toggle()` will show the div if its hidden, and hide it if its visible.
Example:

```
$("#post-full-116").toggle();
$("#post-116").toggle();
```

Alternatively you could check if the div was visible or hidden with this:

```
if ($"#post-116").is(":visible")
{
  $("#post-116").hide();
  $("#post-full-116").show();
}
else
{
  $("#post-116").show();
  $("#post-full-116").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just have a <div id="post-116">Content</div> and add something like class="full" if its the full size version.  If you go from preview to full size view you just find the element with id="post-116" and replace the contents and add the attribute.  If you go from full size view to preview then find the div again and replace the contents and remove the class.